# Date query in nested schema in MongoDB/Mongoose returning result out of range

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm facing this odd result in a query:

My schemas:

```
var taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    done: Boolean,
    dueDate: Date,
    info: String
});

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        tasks:     [ taskSchema ],
}, { usePushEach: true });
```

My query in Robo 3T:

```
db.getCollection('events').find({ 'tasks.dueDate': 
    {
        $gte: new ISODate('2018-04-01T00:00:00'),
        $lte: new ISODate('2018-05-01T00:00:00')
    }
}, { 'tasks.$': 1, _id: 1 }
```

)

Which results:

```
 /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fabc5ec85c3400123cdf5b"),
    "tasks" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Comprar champagne",
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2019-01-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a723e868dba4f0014c0c556"),
            "done" : true
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1c99ccba7cc60014c99945"),
    "tasks" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Prova do vestido",
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2018-05-10T03:00:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a7336d5b882bc0014daeba9"),
            "done" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, that returns me one document with task.dueDate in 2019, out of range of the query.
Why is this happening?

MongoDB version v3.6.3

Thanks in advance!
Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have added your above mentioned data set and ran your query which yield me 0 results: 1) https://i.imgur.com/knh0LZE.png    
2) https://i.imgur.com/b13OW7p.png

Comment: Actually this is not all the document, I contract to better show here. Here you can see all document returned: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1wj0

Comment: Check the query in answer and let me know of that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
db.events.find(
 {tasks:{$elemMatch:{$and:[{dueDate:{$lte: new Date('2018-05-01T00:00:00')}}, 
 {dueDate:{$gte: new Date('2018-04-01T00:00:00')}}]} }     
 }, { 'tasks.$': 1, _id: 1 }
)
```

And the output is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a1c99ccba7cc60014c99945"),
"tasks" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Degustaçao buffet",
        "dueDate" : ISODate("2018-04-02T03:00:00.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7337abb882bc0014daebaa"),
        "done" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This works better but, I need to find any array document (Tasks in the example) in a date range. I have this document:  https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1wj4
Which has two tasks in that range: 
db.events.find(
 {tasks: { $elemMatch: { $and: [
        {dueDate:{$lte: new Date('2018-06-01T00:00:00')}}, 
        {dueDate:{$gte: new Date('2018-04-01T00:00:00')}}
    ]} }     
 }, { 'tasks.$': 1, _id: 1 }
)
But in this case it returns just one document.

Comment: Actually this is another issue. I'm checking your answer as the correct one. Thank you @Rahul Raj!